# wso2 how can we store a message and send it without removing ti

Tags: wso2, esb

we want to use a jdbc store message to store inbound messages.
  Then we want send it one to one but we don't want the message are removed, so we can use jdbc store like a audit system.
  Do you have any samples about this pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Hiro Team.

Comment: you can clone the message using clone mediator...one target point to a sequence with the jdbc store message invocation, the another target point to a sequence to store your message to a audit DB/table

Comment: Also, please note that Stack Overflow is not the best place to get software or code recommendations, and this question is likely to be downvoted. Just warnin' ya.